# Access Help design multiple calculations with parameters

Tags: ms-access

I'm stuck in deciding how best to do calculations. My main table contains marks for students, in which there are 11 subjects in each of the many exams....

I can easily visualize this in a query for each exam or even create a crosstab. I can get the average score **in a report** using calculated control box...

**Question 1:** How can I accomplish this in a query or vba instead of a report? I need a way in which I can compare performance in different exams, Do I also need to store the average in a table for this future reference?

Each exam (11 subjects) is identified by an examdate_id.... It can also be queried through parameters(ExamYear, Semester and examType) which I can get from a form's combo box

Question 2 follows later

[Main table: exams][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJz3A.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a trigger that calculates the average result. Access does not support database-triggers so you have to use a workaround with an event in a form.

- Add the attribute `AverageScore` to your `Exams`-table
- Create another form based on your `Exams`-table. It should have the new attribute `AverageScore`
- You can change the view into datagrid if you like so it looks just like a table.
- In the `form_load`-event you retrieve all IDs from your students and update each `AverageScore` based on the Exams-table ID.
- This solutions will update every single average score every time you load the form so it would be advisable to put it somewhere else. Favorably when you type in the indivual exam results.

Comment: Thanks @eliteraceelephant I've been thinking of your suggestion (still waiting to hear other opinions) But then doesn't it mean that I will always need to say WHERE is AverageScore... or exclude that score if I need to do other calculations? wouldn't ir be easier to use a different table for averages?? Most experts advice against this in forums

Comment: Yes, it should be another table. If there will only be one average score for each student the student table might be a good place. If there are several scores (for example in several years) you definitely need a seperate table. An SQL query with an Inner Join between your tables Exams and where you put average_score will give you the datasource you need.

Comment: In that case I think I could use button to calculate or update averages as it is not necessary to do it every time a score is entered.. biggest logical issue was compounded by numerous advice not to store calculated data

Comment: This question has been answered [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40435697/retrieve-highest-two-scores)