# Retrieve highest two scores

Tags: sql, ms-access

To calculate the average score in an exam I need to get the results for:

subject1 + subject 2 + subject3 + (sum of best 2scores of subject 4, 5, 6) + (Best 2 scores in subject 7,8,9,10,11)

some of the subjects will have null as a student only takes any 3 out of 7,8,9,10,11

Each exam is defined by an ExamDateID

How do I achieve this? (I need the result to populate a new table... Not the scope of this question)

Access 2010

[image: Main table]

Comment: Cut and paste data is a lot easier than a picture.

Comment: Do you need a sql query for this

Comment: @rohit, query is needed to retrieve the exam(11 subjects)... I'm now thinking that I can use some VBA code behind a button or event procedure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using three source queries to be referenced in a final query. Do note, marks that tie in same *ExamDateID* and *Subject* range will be summed up in calculations:

1. Exam Marks for Subjects 1-3 *(using conditional aggregation)*

   ```
   SELECT e.StudentID, e.ExamDateID, 
          SUM(IIF(e.Subject BETWEEN 1 AND 3, e.Marks, NULL)) AS SumMarks123
   FROM ExamTable AS e
   GROUP BY e.StudentID, e.ExamDateID;
   ```
2. Exam Marks for Subjects 4-6 (highest two)  *(using subquery)*

   ```
   SELECT e.StudentID, e.ExamDateID, SUM(e.Marks) AS SumTop2Marks456
   FROM ExamTable AS e
   WHERE e.Subject BETWEEN 4 AND 6 
   AND  (SELECT Count(*) FROM ExamTable sub
         WHERE sub.StudentID = e.StudentID AND sub.ExamDateID = e.ExamDateID
         AND sub.Subject BETWEEN 4 AND 6 AND sub.Marks >= e.Marks)  <= 2
   GROUP BY e.StudentID, e.ExamDateID;
   ```
3. Exam Marks for Subjects 7-11 (highest two)  *(using subquery)*

   ```
   SELECT e.StudentID, e.ExamDateID, SUM(e.Marks) AS SumTop2Marks711
   FROM ExamTable AS e
   WHERE e.Subject BETWEEN 7 AND 11
   AND  (SELECT Count(*) FROM ExamTable sub
         WHERE sub.StudentID = e.StudentID AND sub.ExamDateID = e.ExamDateID
         AND sub.Subject BETWEEN 7 AND 11 AND sub.Marks >= e.Marks)  <= 2
   GROUP BY e.StudentID, e.ExamDateID;
   ```

**Final Query**

```
SELECT a.StudentID, a.ExamDateID, 
       (a.SumMarks123 + b.SumTop2Marks456 + c.SumTop2Marks711) As SumScore
FROM (ExamAvgSubj123Q a 
INNER JOIN ExamAvgSubj456Q b 
    ON (a.ExamDateID = b.ExamDateID) AND (a.StudentID = b.StudentID)) 
INNER JOIN ExamAvgSubj711Q c 
    ON (a.ExamDateID = c.ExamDateID) AND (a.StudentID = c.StudentID);
```

---

Of course there is no reason, you cannot combine all queries into one but as seen can be a bit intense to maintain using derived tables:

```
SELECT a.StudentID, a.ExamDateID, 
       (a.SumMarks123 + b.SumTop2Marks456 + c.SumTop2Marks711) As SumScore    
FROM
   ((SELECT e.StudentID, e.ExamDateID, 
            SUM(IIF(e.Subject BETWEEN 1 AND 3, e.Marks, NULL)) AS SumMarks123
    FROM ExamTable AS e
    GROUP BY e.StudentID, e.ExamDateID) a 

INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT e.StudentID, e.ExamDateID, SUM(e.Marks) AS SumTop2Marks456
   FROM ExamTable AS e
   WHERE e.Subject BETWEEN 4 AND 6 
   AND  (SELECT Count(*) FROM ExamTable sub
         WHERE sub.StudentID = e.StudentID AND sub.ExamDateID = e.ExamDateID
         AND sub.Subject BETWEEN 4 AND 6 AND sub.Marks >= e.Marks)  <= 2
   GROUP BY e.StudentID, e.ExamDateID) b 

ON (a.ExamDateID = b.ExamDateID) AND (a.StudentID = b.StudentID)) 

INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT e.StudentID, e.ExamDateID, SUM(e.Marks) AS SumTop2Marks711
   FROM ExamTable AS e
   WHERE e.Subject BETWEEN 7 AND 11
   AND  (SELECT Count(*) FROM ExamTable sub
         WHERE sub.StudentID = e.StudentID AND sub.ExamDateID = e.ExamDateID
         AND sub.Subject BETWEEN 7 AND 11 AND sub.Marks >= e.Marks)  <= 2
   GROUP BY e.StudentID, e.ExamDateID) c 

ON (a.ExamDateID = c.ExamDateID) AND (a.StudentID = c.StudentID);
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** Added getting the best two scores

I suggest you use VBA in your button_click event. Here is a general outline for the code. You will need to refine it:

```
dim rs as DAO.recordset
dim db as dao.database
set db = current db
dim qry as string
dim avgScore as double
avgScore = 0
numberOfSubject = 0

dim firstBestScore2in3 as double, firstBestScore2in3 as double
firstBestScore2in3 = 0
secondBestScore2in3 = 0

dim firstBestScore2in5 as double, firstBestScore2in5 as double
firstBestScore2in5 = 0
secondBestScore2in5 = 0

'query your database
qry = _
"SELECT studentID, subject, marks " & _
"FROM exams " & _
"WHERE studentID = " & Me.txtStudentID & " " & _
"ORDER BY stubject;"
set rs = db.opendynaset qry

'Iterate through recordset
Do While Not rs.EOF Then

 Select Case rs!subject
  Case 1 To 3
   avgScore = avgScore + rs!subject
  Case 4 To 6
   if (rs!subject > firstBestScore2in3) then
     firstBestScore2in3 = rs!subject
   elseif (rs!subject > secondBestScore2in3) then
     secondBestScore2in3 = rs!subject
   end if
  Case 7 To 11
   if (rs!subject > firstBestScore2in5) then
     firstBestScore2in5 = rs!subject
   elseif (rs!subject > secondBestScore2in5) then
     secondBestScore2in5 = rs!subject
   end if
 end case

 rs.next
loop

avgScore = avgScore + firstBestScore2in3 + secondBestScore2in3 + firstBestScore2in5 + secondBestScore2in5

avgScore = avgScore / 7
```

Comment: Also +1 even if you miss the picking methods.

Comment: Great! I'm so indebted to generous volunteers like yourselves. I'm only 'toddling' in learning sql and as they say, can't beat learning while doing. In class only learnt a few simple queries... Until I hit the wall on this one and asked...I finally decided to go with @parfait considering the experts who advise against storing calculated data....But then I was at the end of my limited wits... eliteraceelephant, Thanks a lot from Kenya(*);

Comment: @eliteraceelephant, apologies for my little knowledge (Which of course I'm trying to increase)... But what part of the code determines that you select 2 records? not 3?  ..... Also, how do I interpret the WHERE clause? how could I insert '''yourstudentID'''?

Comment: @Bonifacey I added the code in my initial answer. WHERE-clause: You should rename the textbox in your form that has the studentID to txtStudentID so you can refer to it in your VBA code. I would appreciate upvotes on my comments. I need reputation to set bounties on my own questions. =)